# How to add a little lump in the middle to <hr> using css?

Tags: html, css

Can any one please tell me who to create a little V shaped lump in between a horizontal line? Please give a CSS solution.

Comment: Do you have an example of what you want. It is a little unclear.

Comment: Hint: another element positioned over `<hr/>` line

Comment: Something like this? http://cssdeck.com/labs/7tzpwew5

Comment: It won't let me add picture: Consider a plain horizontal line. Now go in the middle and add a little V between. So its like a horizontal line joined to another horizontal line with a "V"? It is hard to understand.

Comment: Yes Zvona that is exactly what I want but a bit toward the start thanks :)

Comment: You can use an image for this if you are not comfortable with CSS

Answer (score 1):

You mean sth like here: http://jsfiddle.net/uL4s74y9/

HTML:

```
`<div class="arrow"></div>`
```

CSS:

```
`.arrow {
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 5;
}
.arrow:before{
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -20px; 
    left: 50px;
    z-index: 10;
    border: 10px #fff solid;
    border-top-color: red;
}`
```

Comment: It's simple. You have an element with 10px border, but only one border (top) is with color like .arrow container. (other borders are white, but better way is to set them as transparent - border: 10px transparent solid, because white is poor solution, only for white backgrounds :)

Answer (score 0):

The general concept is that you take an `hr` element and for the V use a pseudo element (e.g. `hr:after` or `hr:before`) and position it in the center.

Here's an example of it in action http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LEZmgp

Based off this [CSS Tricks demo](http://css-tricks.com/examples/hrs/)